# What does it mean that two spaces are equal in the context of dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces, weak-topology

I have a few questions about dual spaces of Banach spaces and what does it mean to two spaces to be equall in this context.

I have a note in my notebook that says "If a space $Y$ is the dual space of other space $X$ then $\overline{B(0,1)} \subset Y$  is $w^*$-compact on $Y$ by Banach-Alaoglu "

The example I have is $\ell^1$: "$\ell^1$ is the dual of $c_0$, and hence the unit ball of $\ell^1$ is $w^*$-compact".

My problem here is what does it mean the word "is"? What class of isomorphism is referring?

I know that $\ell^1$ is isometrically isomorphism to $c_0^*$, and because of this I can make a reasoning like this: By banach alaoglu the unit ball of $c_0^*$ is $w^*-$compact, now consider the $w^*$ topology on $\ell^1$. What I think this means is to put a topology on $\ell^1$ via the identification we have between $\ell^1$ and $c_0^*$, now since this identificacion is an isomorphism, i.e preserves the norm, then the unit ball of $c_0^*$ is identifyed with the unit ball of $\ell^1$ and hence the unit ball of $\ell^1$ is $w^*-$compact. But if the identification is not an isometry I am not sure if I can conclude that the unit ball of $\ell^1$ is $w^*-$compact.

Comment: Your scepticism is very justified by this mathoverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122833/weak-compactness-of-unit-ball-in-equivalent-norm

Comment: The answers in that question seems to answer my question, at least partially. I am going to analyze it more deeply! and then give it as an answer